# what does the return value of cudaDeviceProp::asyncEngineCount mean?

Tags: asynchronous, cuda

I have read the documentation, and it said that if it returns 1: 
`device can concurrently copy memory between host and device while executing a kernel`

If it is 2: 
`device can concurrently copy memory between host and device in both directions and execute a kernel at the same time`

What exactly is the difference?

Comment: 1 DMA engine: (download ***or*** upload data) + execute kernels. 2 DMA engines: download data + upload data + execute kernels.

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae: How about you provide that as an answer. I'd accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With 1 DMA engine, the device can either download data from the CPU or upload data to the CPU, but not do both simultaneously. With 2 DMA engines, the device can do both in parallel.

Regardless of the number of available DMA engines, the device also has an execution engine which can be running a kernel in parallel of ongoing memory operations.

Comment: Correct. And, in both cases, the device can also be executing a kernel at the same time. `AsyncEngineCount == 0` is also a possible value, in which case the device cannot perform memory copies and kernel executions in parallel.

Comment: Why is this value related to DMA engines?Any official material about this?thks.